# Buttons not getting displayed

Tags: android

I have the following code defined in my xml file, but I don't see the buttons getting displayed. I have read way too many posts, and pretty much tried all possible combinations, but no luck :( I'd really appreciate if someone could help me here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/ad_desc"
    android:inputType="text" />    

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text="@string/phone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sms" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:text="@string/maps" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="@string/video" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to see my App Name on top (Text view - @string/hello_world), right beneath it, a big box that allows me to EditText(@string/ad_desc), and beneath that, all my buttons. The button should be at the bottom, next to each other aligned in this manner - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/ (Linear layout - Horizontal example), except I want my buttons to be at the bottom, and not at the top. Instead I see something else (Image attached)[image]

Please feel free to ask me if you'd like me to attach anything else. I am new to Android programming, and this is totally beyond me on why it isn't working.

Comment: Add the root view too.

Comment: I am not sure why the layout didn't get pasted in my original post. Edited, and reposted my xml. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you want it to be horizontal, the orientation must be set to  horizontal not vertical.

Comment: Changed it. I see the buttons now, but they have gone on the top, and are vertically placed. I tried changing android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal", but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align your `Buttons` at the bottom then you are better off with a `RelativeLayout` as the root. Try changing it to the following and notice the properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:hint="@string/ad_desc"
    android:inputType="text"
    androidi:layout_below="@id/textView2" />  
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text="@string/phone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sms" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:text="@string/maps" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="@string/video" />  
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout >
```

You may have to add some margin to the `TextView` and `EditText` for appropriate spacing but this should give you your `TextView` with the `EditText` below it and your `Button`s in a horizontal `LinearLayout` aligned at the bottom of the screen.

**Edit**

Notice this property

```
androidi:layout_below="@id/textView2"
```

of the `EditText` and this property

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Of the `LinearLayout` that I added.

Comment: I tried that. I see the below error - This LinearLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no 
 style)

Comment: Did you use just this and take out the `LinearLayout` that you had? And that's not an error but a warning. Its good to take those out but shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Sure. Let me try, and see if it works. I will update you shortly.

Comment: It didn't work. I created a new activity_main xml file, and added the contents above. I am getting an error in the Activity class - setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) - activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: That's not due to this code. You need to make sure you don't have any xml errors and clean your project. Try replacing the layout you have in your question with this code and make sure you have no errors then see what you get

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error? Make sure there are no errors in any xml files including the manifest

Comment: You might change this line `androidi:layout_below="@id/textView2"` in your `EditText` to `androidi:layout_below="@+id/textView2"`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I really appreciate your patience in working with me. I get the error in the activity class. And nope, there are no errors in the xml file. I didn't have the error in the Activity class before. After pasting the above xml contents, I get the error - activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: If you have `R.java` in the `gen` folder try deleting that and let it rebuild

Comment: Yes, it worked :) THANKS so much. The buttons have gone too much at the bottom though. I am not sure how to attach the screenshot here since I am using the comment box.

Comment: I could actually drag the buttons and bring them up. So it works :) Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. You could even use `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` (20) being an example in your `LinearLayout` which is probably what the dragging did.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to create a new relative layout, and place the item that you need from the palette. 
Or start to try and learn to make matrioska layout via xml ;)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html